# curl - http patch issue [using cookie as well as usr/pwd]

Tags: http, session, cookies, curl

I am trying to update an object using curl.

There are 2 approaches I am trying:
1] Provide usr/pswd in patch reques
    => says "Warning: You can only select one HTTP request!"
2] Save login cookie first and use it to perform patch
    with -I =>  says "Warning: You can only select one HTTP request!"
    without -I  => [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

Here are the requests:
1] Provide usr/pswd in patch request

```
curl -I -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: application/json" -X PATCH -d '{"field":"new_value"}' -D- 'https://url?un=<uname>&pw=<pwd>/<path to obj>/<key>' --trace-ascii trace.OUT
Warning: You can only select one HTTP request!
```

2] Save login cookie first and use it to perform patch

```
curl -c cookies.txt  'https://url?un=<uname>&pw=<pwd>'    
curl -b cookies.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: application/json" -X PATCH -d '{"field":"new_value"}' -D- 'https://url/<path to obj>/<key>'  
  =>[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
curl **-I** cookies.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: application/json" -X PATCH -d '{"field":"new_value"}' -D- 'https://url/<path to obj>/<key>'  
  =>  Warning: You can only select one HTTP request!
```

We have a tool that can perform the patch using a UI and I checked the request/headers in firebug and seems like I have everything in the request. However I want to script this call.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that application/json has no defined semantics for PATCH.

Answer (score 3):

"-I" implies a HEAD request, but you specify a HTTP method of "PATCH". Curl complains that it can't do both at the same time.

Comment: well, specifically it is actually -d that collides with -I but yes the command line specifies two (different) request methods

Comment: Thanks @Julian Reschke . I thought -I is just for getting headers back of any request , but seems like its headers of a GET request. That explains the "You can select only one HTTP response". So I am left with  [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}] , even after I save the cookies and use them .